# Show alertDialog setpositiveButton only when some conditions are true

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to enable `positivebutton` of an `AlertDialog` only when text are set in both `editText` field, but this is not working, i.e. `PositiveButton` does not show up even when I have text in both field.

Of course, if I don't have text in both field, I am getting error `NumberFormatException: empty String`

```
  case R.id.action_geolocate:
    AlertDialog.Builder placePicker = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View view = li.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place, null);
    placePicker.setView(view);
    placePicker.setTitle("Enter Latitude and Longitude");
    final EditText lat2 = view.findViewById(R.id.lati2);
    final EditText long2 = view.findViewById(R.id.longi2);
    if (lat2.getText().toString().length()>0 && long2.getText().toString().length()>0) {
      placePicker.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          Lat = Double.parseDouble(lat2.getText().toString());
          Long = Double.parseDouble(long2.getText().toString());
          setupViewPager();
        }
      });
    }
    placePicker.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    placePicker.show();
    return true;
```

**Update**

```
        placePicker.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        AlertDialog pp = placePicker.create();

        pp.show();
        pp.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lat2.getText().toString())){
          pp.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
        }
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before checking the length of your `String`s, verify they aren't `null` :

    `if ((lat2.getText()!=null) && (long2.getText()!=null)) {
        if (lat2.getText().toString().length()>0 && long2.getText().toString().length()>0) {...`

Comment: that does not change any thing. which is understandable. if this is null, I may have null point exception, but that has nothing to do with visibility. Also, I am yet to find an exemple of set with non zero length, but  null.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom Dialog instead of AlertDialog. In the XML view, set visibility attribute to the positive button to "gone".
Then, in the java code setting up the Dialog, setup `.addTextChangedListener()` to the EditText views and in those listeners, check the length of the string entered and you can decide when to call `positiveButton.visibility(View.VISIBLE);` to make the positive button appear.